# How to implement dynamic filtering in Django ListView based on user input?

Tags: django, filter

I'm working on a Django project where I need to display a list of items and allow users to filter the items based on various criteria. I'm using Django's generic ListView for displaying the items, but I'm not sure how to implement the dynamic filtering based on the user's input.

Here's my current setup:
models

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

views:

```
class ItemListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "items/item_list.html"
```

item_list.html

```
{% for item in object_list %}
    <div class="item">
        <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
        <p>Category: {{ item.category }}</p>
        <p>Price: {{ item.price }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'd like to allow users to filter the items by category, price range, and availability. What's the best way to implement this functionality in a Django ListView? Any guidance or examples would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use query parameters in your  tags of your html template.

For example do something like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'ItemList' %}?category=books"></a>
```

Then, in your views you can use `get_queryset()` or `get_context_data()` to filter the items. Something like this:

```
class ItemListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "items/item_list.html"
       
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        category_parameter = self.request.GET.get("category")
        items = Item.objects.filter(category=category_parameter)
        return {'Items': items}
```